# How to receive data sent by Ajax in a .jsp file

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

I am using Ajax call in JQuery to send some data to a JSP file.  Here is the code:

```
$.post("myscript.jsp",
    { sg: data1, st: data2 },
    function(data){
       alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    }
);
```

My question is, how can I receive the data in myscript.jsp?
I need the data to perform some calculations in jsp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get parameter from request like :

```
String data1 = request.getParameter("sg");
String data2 = request.getParameter("st");
```

Comment: Method .getParameter() will retirn BOTH POST and GET parameters

Comment: Oh great! Just the answer I need.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
            var params ="your parameters to send";

            var resultStringX = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"myscript.jsp",//jsp,servlet,struts action
            data: params,
            async: false
            }).responseText;
            resultStringX=$.trim(resultStringX);

            //here the result will be stored in resultStringX
```

or

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#call').click(function ()
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "myscript.jsp", //here you can use servlet,jsp, etc
                    data: "input=" +$('#ip').val()+"&output="+$('#op').val(),
                    success: function(msg){      
                            $('#output').append(msg);
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    input:<input id="ip" type="text" name="" value="" /><br></br>
    output:<input id="op" type="text" name="" value="" /><br></br>
    <input type="button" value="Call JSP" name="Call JSP" id="call"/>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying on the ajax call.  After the data is sent to the jsp file, how do you use the data.  For instance, do you just say something like: String abc = ip?

Comment: you can replace the content using ajax into a div like parent.document.getElementById("replaceToEdit").innerHTML=resultStringX;

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate your insight to this too.