# JSP - Access Jquery Ajax Data

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

I'm sending following Ajax request to `mypage.jsp`

```
   jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../mypage.jsp",
        data: {
            param1: 'aaa',
            param2: 'bbb'
        },
        contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);    
        }
    });
```

In my `mypage.jsp` page, I'm trying to access `param1` as below.

```
String result = request.getParameter("param1");
```

but the `result` becomes `null`.

However, when I change my ajax request as below, I get `'aaa'` as the result (which is the desired output).

```
   jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../mypage.jsp?param1=aaa&param2=bbb",
        data: {},
        contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);    
        }
    });
```

Am I using the correct method to access the data being sent by the Ajax request?

I referred some docs on Implicit Request (HTTPServletRequest) object, but could not think of any other suitable method to access data other than `'request.getParameter()'`

How do I access `param1` without sending it in the Ajax request URL?

Note:
I also encountered a very similar SO question '[How to receive data sent by Ajax in a .jsp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063218/how-to-receive-data-sent-by-ajax-in-a-jsp-file)' but it's not using a 'data' field as I do, hence thought to ask this question.

Comment: try it with the parameter name  `'param1':'aaa'` or create a js object to hold the data the object and then call the `JSON.strigify(obj)` on the object.

Comment: I would also change it to `$.ajax()`.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me, although I'm not sure whether this and the request in the question are equivalent. However, this way, I was able to read the parameters successfully:

```
new Ajax.Request('../mypage.jsp', {
    method: 'POST',
    asynchronous: false,
    parameters: {
        param1: 'aaa',
        param2: 'bbb'
    },
    onSuccess: function (data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data.responseText.trim());
    }
})
```

Note that I had to modify the `onSuccess` function (`data.responseText.trim()`), when reading `data`, because here `data` is an object.